# infinite redirection

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

The problem happens similarly, but not equally in Firefox and Chrome. In Firefox, I couldn't login (but now can) and save feed changes (and still can't). In Chrome, I was always able to login, but never save feed changes. To reproduce:

At http://www.alltop.com/:

1. create an account
2. click manage feeds
3. change some
4. click save changes

It'll redirect you forever instead of saving the changes. Does this happen to you too or is this only in my computer?

Comment: Your question starts like it is an answer to something, to what? If multiple browsers show the same problem, it is more likely that the website has a bug...

Comment: Why do you think it starts like an answer to something?

Answer (score 0):

Sites usually fail like that if you block cookies or `Referer` header.

Any firewalls, proxies, privacy software? Try disabling them.

Or better — write to site's support.